# To make this sentence clearer shall I use a colon?

Tags: grammar, commas, colons

In the following sentence as an example, the speaker meets two strangers that happen to be a fox and a cat.

**As he turned a corner, he came face to face with two strangers, a fox and a cat.**

Should the comma be changed to a colon in order to indicate that the only strangers are the fox and the cat? Otherwise, it sounds like he is meeting 4 'people'.

Comment: Well, you've answered your own question.

Comment: Colons in this usage are rather old-fashioned nowadays; a dash (people in the US generally prefer an em-dash, while I'd say most Brits, myself included, prefer a spaced en-dash) is better in all but the most formal writing.

Comment: Yeah, the comma suggests four characters. An em dash would work well here, though it is a bit breezy (informal): *As he turned a corner, he came face to face with two strangers—a fox and a cat.* A colon is nice if you want a formal touch: *As he turned a corner, he came face to face with two strangers: a fox and a cat.* For drama, it would be worth breaking a rule: *As he turned a corner, he came face to face with two strangers. A fox and a cat.*

Comment: This is a somewhat strange appositive. Normally, an appositive that is set off with punctuation is highly restrictive. In your example, it is merely descriptive. I'd tend to use a lexical fix here ... two strangers, to wit, a fox and a cat. Or you could individualize them as proper nouns ... two strangers, Fox and Cat.